# Why isn't my button working every time and why is it not printing the first 6 FIRST?

Tags: javascript

I am building a little project: A random quote generator.

I have 6 quotes stored as objects in a file, `quotes.js`. Each quote object has a `quote` and `source`. Some of them also have a `citation` and `year`.

I have an html page (plus CSS) that displays a quote on the screen. There is also a button to click: `click to get a new quote`.

My code largely runs, when I click the button on my page, it loads a new quote at random. The majority of the time...

However, I am also aiming to NOT display a random quote more than once until ALL quotes from the array have been displayed first.

This is not happening yet.

My button, at random, does not work. I may get 5 successful button clicks, a miss and then another success at random. I'm not sure why this is happening at all.

Can you please suggest what to do here? No errors are being caught in the console.

ACTUALLY, I suppose that the button IS working everytime, it's just loading the same quote again.

Here is my main code:

```
// event listener to respond to "Show another quote" button clicks
// when user clicks anywhere on the button, the "printQuote" function is called
document.getElementById('loadQuote').addEventListener("click", printQuote, false);


// prints quote
function printQuote(){

    var finalQuote = buildQuote();

    document.getElementById('quote-box').innerHTML = finalQuote;
}


// builds message for html, adding on citation and/or year if necessary
function buildQuote(){
    var quote2Print = getQuote(); 
    var message;
    message = "<p class='quote'>" + quote2Print.quote + "</p><p class='source'>" + quote2Print.source;

    if(quote2Print.hasOwnProperty('citation') === true){
        citation = quote2Print.citation;
        message += "<span class='citation'>"  + quote2Print.citation + "</span>";

        if(quote2Print.hasOwnProperty('year') === true){
            year = quote2Print.year;
            message += "<span class='year'>" + quote2Print.year  + "</span></p>";
            return message;

        } else {
            return message += "</p>";
        }

    }else {
        return message;
    }
}


// makes sure that if all 6 quotes haven't been printed, getRandomQuote is called again until a new one is found
function getQuote(){
    var countArray = [];
    var quote;

    if(countArray.length < 6){

        quote = getRandomQuote();

        while(countArray.indexOf(quote) === -1)
        {
            if(countArray.indexOf(quote) === -1) {
                countArray.push(quote);
                return quote;

            } else{
                quote = getRandomQuote();
            }
        } 

    } else {
        quote = getRandomQuote();
        return quote;
    }
}


// With random number, goes through array of quotes and chooses one. random number = index position
function getRandomQuote(){
    var randomQuoteNum = randomQuoteNo();
    var quote = quotes[randomQuoteNum];
    return quote;
}


// Gets a random number
function randomQuoteNo() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good method of doing it. A better way is to randomly shuffle the array (lookup fisher yates shuffle) and then just take items from the array sequentially.

Comment: The logic of your `getQuote` function is hard to follow. For example `if(countArray.length < 6)` will always be `true` and `while(countArray.indexOf(quote) === -1)` will always run only once because you return from the function when this condition is true.

Answer (score -1):

Going about this the easy way is, ofc, the easy way. So that's what I've done.
Basically you have an array of quotes that you load from somewhere. This you want shuffled (or randomised or whatever). And then you want to add one quote at a time to the quotes that are to be displayed? I have read your question as such and done a solution for that.

Here is a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/CfdqQv1nGwdaIfYrbXr4?p=preview
And here is the code:

```
var quotes = [];
quotes.push(createQuote(1));
quotes.push(createQuote(2));
quotes.push(createQuote(3));
quotes.push(createQuote(4));
quotes.push(createQuote(5));
quotes.push(createQuote(6));
quotes.push(createQuote(7));

function createQuote(number) {
  return {
    id: number,
    text: "text" + number,
    author: "author" + number
  };
}

var printedQuotes = [];
var nonPrintedQuotes = [];

init();

function init() {
  nonPrintedQuotes = shuffle(quotes);
  printVars();
}

function addQuoteToPrint() {
  if (nonPrintedQuotes.length > 0) {
    console.log("ADD QUOTE!");
    var quote = nonPrintedQuotes.slice(-1, nonPrintedQuotes.length)
    nonPrintedQuotes = nonPrintedQuotes.splice(0, nonPrintedQuotes.length - 1);

    printedQuotes.push(quote[0]);
    printVars();
  } else {
    console.log("No more quotes to print. Sorry. :/")
  }

}

function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length;
  var shuffled = array.slice(); // Copy the array

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    var t = shuffled[m];
    shuffled[m] = shuffled[i];
    shuffled[i] = t;
  }

  return shuffled;
}

function printVars() {
  console.log(quotes);
  console.log(nonPrintedQuotes);
  console.log(printedQuotes);
}
```

So basically, you load up your quotes somehow (I've created a little helper function just to easily create some fake quote objects). Then you create a shuffled array of those (don't know if you want to keep the original array sorted or not, so I left it sorted). Then when you say you want a quote, you take one element from the shuffled array and put in in the printed array.

I've used a fisher yates shuffle (as per EvanTrimboli's suggestion). 
When you've loaded all the quotes, you can trigger your function  to fetch more.

Comment: Please explain the down vote. Why down vote a fully functional answer?